# windowIsFloating attribute in Android theme

Tags: android, window, themes

What does this attribute really do?

I've read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#isFloating%28%29) and I understand what it's supposed to be. However, when I use it in a theme (I created a style with the `android:Theme.Dialog` as the parent), changing the value for this attribute doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: What window are you changing it on?

Comment: i used it in a style named ThemePop, this style is used for pop-up windows.

Comment: I just used it to create a transparent background Activity. I found that when I set it to true, the window would shrink to wrap the contents of the contained views, even though the views all had 'android:layout_width="fill_parent"'. When I set it to false, the window took up the entire device width.

Comment: I'm using ActionBar in my Activity and when I change it to true I get an exception: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: ActionBarImpl can only be used with a compatible window decor layout"

Answer (score 24):

I don't know all of the effects of setting `windowIsFloating` to `true`, but one thing that I noticed is that when it is set to `true`, the activity would not expand the width to fill the screen, even if you set the layout width to `match_parent` (i.e. `android:layout_width="match_parent"`)

Comment: to fix it use this code```<item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">100%</item>
   <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">100%</item>
   <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>```

Answer (score 11):

From my experiments, it seems to affect how the window reacts to the soft input. It you set this to false, the window won't slide up when the keyboard becomes visible.

Answer (score 9):

When you use **Dialog Theme**, this attribute default is true.

```
<style name="Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        ...
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        ...
</style>
```

And in this case, the `Dialog` will create PhoneWindow with this code:

```
    if (mIsFloating) {
        setLayout(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT);
        setFlags(0, flagsToUpdate);
    }
```

It will cause contentView always wrap content as small as. You could set it to false or Manual update the `Dialog` window layout to MATCH_PARENT like this:

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    dialog?.window?.setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using really naïve code to show a bottom sheet dialog fragment. However, my dialog was covering bottom navigation bar in light mode. See the picture below:

After adding the item to my dialog theme, this issue got resolved.

```
<style name="myTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateAlwaysHidden|adjustNothing</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
</style>
```

[image]